# Can I Hash Map 3 class in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
units = new HashMap<Integer,Unit>();
staffs = new HashMap<Integer,Staff>();
```

Can I map unit class and staff class to course class like this? I want to store the data into dat file as serialized data.

My scenario is like this. Course have many units and course have 1 director and 1 deputy director which are from staff class.

I did like the first one. The problem is that I got a class called database.java and in there I have a method like this.

```
public boolean setDatabase(ArrayList<Course> iCourse, Map<Integer,Unit> iUnit)
```

So if I use this:

```
courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
units = new HashMap<Integer,Unit>();
staffs = new HashMap<Integer,Staff>();
```

Can I try this below?

```
public boolean setDatabase(ArrayList<Course> iCourse, Map<Integer,Unit> iUnit, Map<Integer,Staff> iStaff)
```

Comment: what is the significance of `( ` ??

Comment: I guess OP hadn't used the code block earlier, causing SO not to display `<>`.

Comment: I'd just put `units` and `staffs` inside `courses` and hash that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
public final class Course {
    Staff director;
    Staff deputyDirector;
    List<Unit> units;
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to force Director and Deputy Director, then you can subclass your Staff class like below,

```
public final class Director extends Staff {
    ...
}

public final class DeputyDirector extends Staff {
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Don't make your `Staff` class `final`, otherwise you can't make these subclasses.

And then let your `Course` class use those specific classes, like below,

```
public final class Course {
    Director director;
    DeputyDirector deputyDirector;
    List<Unit> units;
    ...
}
```

**[Edited]**

I have no idea what `setDatabase()` method suppose to do. I would suggest you to come up with a meaningful name. However, if you follow my suggestion you would be able to define your method as follows,

```
public boolean setDatabase(List<Course> courses) {
    ...
}
```

`Course` object will have related `Staff` and `Unit` objects associated with it.